# Pathos (python module) behaves different in IDE and shell

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pycharm, pathos

I am trying to understand how to use the Pathos package to run a function that calls a function. It was my understanding an the advantage of Pathos over the main multiprocessing package was that it allowed functions inside functions. However, I can't seem to make it work. Here is the simplest example I could come up with:

```
def testf(x):
    print(x)

import dill
import pathos
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
pool = ProcessingPool(nodes=3)
out2 = pool.map(testf, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
pool.close()
```

Output:

```
multiprocess.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pathos/helpers/mp_helper.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    func = lambda args: f(*args)
  File "<input>", line 2, in testf
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
"""
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pathos/multiprocessing.py", line 136, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 260, in map
return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/james/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 608, in get
raise self._value
NameError: name 'print' is not defined
```

Edit: It seems that if I paste this code into a shell console, it works fine. No dice if I run it from my IDE of choice, PyCharm. So now my question is why the same code would work differently in the same version of the python interpreter (3.6.1) based on whether it is run from a shell or the in-app console/

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `pathos`. You seem to have overridden (the built-in) `print` function somewhere (which you haven't shown in your question) in your code.

Comment: I ran the example you posted without getting an exception.

Comment: It seems that this only happens when I run from an IDE, but not when I paste the exact same code into python running in the shell. Now I'm even more confused.